# Heat insulation thickness needed for a truck box conversion

Tags: heat-transfer, thermal-insulation, insulator

I'm starting to work on a project of converting a truck box to a motor-home,
and one of the key components for me is heat insulation.
I'm from a sunny country with temperatures that in summer can go up to 40C-45C.
Two main reasons that it's a big problem for me:

1. The most important one is my dog, If I leave for a few hours, I wanna know it's not gonna heat up like a car. I will leave the AC on of course, but I won't be calm if I know that in the event of an AC failure my dog will not be safe.
2. Power saving of course. (On the cold days, there is no sun and no need to heat the place).

Anyway, I can build any box I want, but every inch counts, as I only have a max of 98 inches. I want to figure out what will be the most efficient insulation per inch

- I think the regular bare aluminum box is out of the question
- Rockwool will give good performance, but I'm gonna need 2 inches per wall with the aluminum box
- What about a fiberglass (fabric + epoxy with honeycomb core) at about 1 inch? Or maybe fiberglass <-> core <-> carbon?
- Two decoupled boxes with an air gap and a large blower venting air from the gap?
- Wood? A bit heavy, and a bit weak

Any other ideas?

- Note that weight also matters, so things like concrete are not gonna be suitable.

Comment: Search materials used for insulation. Concrete not a good choice. Check out R values and expanded foam.

Comment: Check on youtube - lots of conversions show insulation being fitted.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've seen a lot of them, but they do say that even after what they did it still gets hot, so I'm looking for things that they haven't thought of, like a fiberglass with nomax core

Comment: So apply the first principle - don't let the heat onto  the van body. Park in shade or have a "sail" to give shade. Or make the van body a reflector... Why do white cars stay cooler than black ones...

Comment: Yes but the problem with the shade is that My solar won't charge

Comment: Walls are normally of 1" square Al tube welded or bolted together. Insulation is usually fiberglass batt that is the lightest stuff you've ever seen - looks like a dryer sheet frizzed up. Roofs are normally 2" thick. Same wispy insulation though under the styrofoam and ply roof (galvanized steel beams are the norm). Floors are usually just built up with an insulating subfloor. Underbelly and utilities can have any degree of winterization you like. Some can be roaded in -20 F fully provisioned, with remote furnace controls for when you stop at a gas station. I had a '63 Airstream that could.

Comment: Aerogel can get a theoretical #1 spot, with expanded polyurethane being a far runner up.  These all need structure that prevents them from being crushed so you'll have to concern yourself with that too.  For strength to weight, carbon fiber does well.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a box at an initial temperature $T_o$ with a surrounding temperature $T_\infty$. Your concern ultimately should be with how long you can leave the box unattended before its inside temperature reaches $T_\infty$. Assume that all external factors remain the same; all that you are able to change is the insulation around the box. The time scale for how temperature changes is primarily established by the thermal diffusivity $\alpha$ (m$^2$/s)

$$\alpha = \frac{k}{\rho \tilde{C}_p}$$

where $k$ is thermal conductivity (W/m $^o$K), $\rho$ is density (kg/m$^3$), and $\tilde{C}_p$ is specific heat capacity (J/kg $^o$K).

Consider that you will wrap the box in a specific thickness of insulation $L_c$ (m). When all external factors remain constant (e.g. the external convection coefficient), a representative time constant for changing the relative temperature inside the box $\theta = (T - T_o)/(T_\infty - T_o)$ is on the order

$$t_c = L_c^2/\alpha$$

For example, when you compare different cases where the insulation remains fixed at a thickness $L_c$, the inside of the box will take longer to change temperature to its halfway point ($\theta = 0.5$) for insulations where $\alpha$ is smaller.

From this, you can see that you should insulate the box with materials having the lowest $\alpha$. Search for materials with low thermal conductivity, high density, and high specific heat capacity.

For a practical approach to materials selection, create a spreadsheet with columns for material, $k$, $\rho$, and $\tilde{C}_p$. Add cells for the area that you should need to wrap $A$ (m$^2$) and thickness that you might wrap $L_c$. Calculate $\alpha = k/\rho \tilde{C}_p$, time constant $t_c = L_c^2/\alpha$, insulation mass $m = \rho (A L_c)$, and time constant per mass $t_c/m = (L_c/A)/(\tilde{C}_p/k)$ (s/kg). The last factor will tell you in a relative way how much longer your dog will survive per added mass of insulation that you put on your box.